# Old Elixir in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: css, less, laravel-5, ecmascript-6, laravel-elixir

I'm playing with Elixir in Laravel 5.1. It works fine, except it seems like it doesn't provide features described in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/elixir) as new. For example, I'm unable to use `mix.babel()` method:

> ```
> mix.babel('l5.js');
>     ^ TypeError: undefined is not a function
> ```

Other than that, `mix.less(['one.less', 'two.less'])` compiles to two separate .css files instead to one app.css, which is supposed to be a new feature.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I found out what was wrong. It was the Laravel installer. Be careful if you use it - it's very convenient, but it seems like it's not being constantly updated. It created Laravel project with newest vendors, but my application files, including `packages.json` were outdated.

Use `composer create-project laravel/laravel my-project --prefer-dist` instead.

Comment: I experienced the same problem, where for some reason the laravel-elixir v1.0.0 was loaded.